# Shader doesn't work when object is inverted by axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader

I have simple shader that imitates "Filled" Image Type for SpriteRenderer. It allows to cut off part of sprite depending of it's fill amount.
But shader doesn't work if Object is inverted by any axis (no matter is it inverted by rotation, scale or "Flip" checkbox on SpriteRenderer).
When Object is inverted Sprite isn't drawn at all.

Shader:

```
Shader "Custom/ProgressShaderUpToDown" {
Properties{
    _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Progress("Progress (Float)", Float) = 0
    _Color("Tint", Color) = (1.0, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0)
}

SubShader{
    Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" }
    Pass{
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma vertex vert_img
    #pragma fragment frag

    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform float _Progress;
uniform fixed4 _Color;

    float4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR
    {
        float4 result = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

        if (i.uv.y > _Progress)
        {
            result.a = 0;
        }

        return result*_Color;
    }
        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the face becomes "back-facing" after being flipped and gets culled. Try disabling culling by adding `Cull Off` after `Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha`.